# Objective C Ternary operator gives error: implicit conversion to 'void' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm finding that the current production version of Xcode is giving me an error when I use the ternary operator like so:

```
//If address.title is not nil, leave it alone. Else, set it to @"".
address.title   ?: [address setTitle:@""];
address.street  ?: [address setStreet:@""];
```

When I use a beta preview for Xcode 5.1, i get no such warning. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Conditionals with Omitted Operands"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) are a GCC extension (also understood by Clang),
and

```
address.title ? : [address setTitle:@""];
```

is equivalent to

```
address.title ? address.title : [address setTitle:@""];
```

with the only difference that `address.title` is evaluated only once.

Now the second operand has pointer type (`NSString *`) and the 
third operator has `void` type. In this case the result type of the conditional
expression would be `void`,  but ARC does not allow the implicit conversion of `NSString *` to `void`. This would compile:

```
 address.title ? (void)0: [address setTitle:@""];
```

but, as Merlevede already said, it is much clearer to use an explict if-statement.

If the compiler contained in the beta preview for Xcode 5.1 does not give an error
then it could be a bug in the compiler. Of course it could also be another language
extension that I do not know of!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

```
 address.title   ?: [address setTitle:@""];
```

should be

```
 address.title =  (address.title)? address.title : @"";
 // or
 [address setTitle:((address.title)? address.title : @"")];
```

The general syntax is

```
 var = (condition) ? value_if_true : value_if_false;  // general syntax
```

In your case it would be better to do

```
if (!address.title)
    address.title = @"";
```

Comment: Using the OP's shortcut, which is valid, you'd also have `address.title = address.title ?: @""` though I agree that the if statement is clearest here.

Comment: `x ? : y` is not generally wrong, it is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).